# How can I play two animatedVectorDrawables sequentially?

Tags: android, android-animation, animatedvectordrawable

I saw this tutorials ([1](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/re-animation-7869722af206) and [2](https://android.jlelse.eu/animatedvectordrawablecompat-3d9568727c53)) about using `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat`.

What's the way to play two animatedVectorDrawables sequentially?

For `ObjectAnimator` I would use `AnimatorSet`. For `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat` I should use `AnimationCallback` ?

```
    if (drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) {
      AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat avdc = (AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat) drawable;
      avdc.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback(){
        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {

        };        
      });
      avdc.start();
}
```

I saw it's problematic for API and I thought to ask if there is a cleaner way.

[image]